# Flask + python + jinja2: how can I partialy replace template arguments with html code?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a function to automatically replace issue IDs to links:

```
def addlinks(text):
    from flask import Markup
    idlist = getallissueids()
    for issueid in idlist:
        text = text.replace( issueid, "<a href=/browse/" + issueid +">" + issueid + "</a>")
    return Markup(text)
```

Then {{text}} is passed to template.

It works, but there is a side effect - all kind of html is unescaped in text after this.
Is there any way to avoid html escaping only for the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the workaroung I found during this night:

```
def addlinks(text):
    from flask import Markup
    idlist = getallissueids()
    for issueid in idlist:
        parts = text.split(issueid)
        text = Markup("<a href=/browse/" + issueid +">" + issueid + "</a>").join(parts)     
    return text
```

Could you please explain how could I do the same thing using this "safe" feature?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The basic idea is that the safe keyword turns off auto-escaping of html found in jinja2 templates.

Answer (score 2):

use the safe filter on text. it would look like this in the template,

```
{{ text |safe }}
```

safe will state that the html found in this text is safe to render and as such doesn't have to be escaped.

[the flask page on templates briefly talks about the safe filter around half way down the tutorial.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/) The safe filter just says that everything in this text is safe and turns off html escaping.